# Adding Two Vectors of Different Size: Optimal Run-time and Optimal Memory Management

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, vector, bit-manipulation

I am looking for a run-time-efficient gadget that adds (pairwise) the value of integers stored in two vectors of integers (`vector<int> a` and `vector<int> b`) that is memory-efficient as well. The vector sizes will be assumed to be either different or equal.

---

What I've got is this:

```
    vector<int> c;
    if( a.size() > b.size() )
    {
       for( size_t i = 0 ; i < b.size() ; ++i )
       {
          c.push_back(a[i]+b[i]);
       }
    else if ( a.size() < b.size() )
    {
       for( size_t i = 0 ; i < a.size() ; ++i )
       {
          c.push_back(a[i]+b[i]);
       }
    }
    else
    {
       for( size_t i = 0 ; i < a.size() ; ++i )
       {
          c.push_back(a[i]+b[i]);
       }
    }
```

---

Example:

`vector<int> a` -> (0)(12)(0)(0)(123)(12)

`vector<int> b` -> (305)(10)(3)(4)(8201)(230)(0)(0)(0)

`vector<int> c` -> (305)(22)(3)(4)(8324)(242)(0)(0)(0)

Comment: Assuming that the sizes will be either different or equal seems like a fair assumption...

Comment: Why does your code contradict your example? I for one based my answer on your code, before the example was added.

Comment: Because I haven't put everything together in my brain yet.

Comment: If you want your algorithm to be both fast and memory efficient, you should consider adding in-place instead of using a third vector to hold your results. Using jroks anwser, you'd replace `begin(c)` with `begin(a)` and forget about vector c altogether.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
#include <algorithm>  // for transform and min
#include <functional> // for std::plus
#include <iterator>   // for std::begin, but it's
                      // implicitly included by <vector>
std::vector<int> a;
std::vector<int> b;
auto size = std::min(a.size(), b.size()); 
std::vector<int> c(size); // creates the third vector big enough for results

std::transform(
    begin(a), begin(a)+size, begin(b),
    begin(c), std::plus<int>()
);
```

Underneath `std::transform` is just a loop that takes one element from each range (defined by first three parameters), applies the binary function on them (the last parameter, `std::plus<int>`) and stores the result in the third range (fourth parameter).

It doesn't get any better w.r.t. "runtime efficiency" than iterating through all the elements. Your solution is near optimal. But standard algorithms have the added benefit of clear intent and that the compiler probably knows how to optimize them efficiently.

Comment: What does `transform` do here? You left out comments for the key piece.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the link above, but, in your own words, what does this do?

Comment: Funny thing is, I *know* your solution will yield the very same assembly code as mine. But I can't bring myself to understand those convolutions. O_o +1 anyway.

Comment: I see... Can this be done with subtraction and multiplication too?

Comment: @LoieBenedicte sure, just replace `std::plus` with `std::minus` or `std::multiplies`.

Comment: @syam Is it *that* convoluted? :)

Comment: @jrok TBH I've seen much worse. But that doesn't stop **me** from thinking a mere loop is more readable. YMMV of course, it's just a style opinion nothing else. :) (in other words, it doesn't really matter)

Comment: @syam The loop is indeed pretty trivial here and I agree, to each his own. But try writing a loop for `set_intersection`, for example :)

Comment: @jrok I'll grant you that, no problem. Still, I prefer KISS as long as I can (emphasis on the last S because that's what I'd rather be -- unless I *really* need otherwise). :p Again YMMV, I guess it's just a matter of habit.

Comment: I get the following error: `type name not allowed`. There is a squiggly red underline on `plus<int>`.

Comment: @LoieBenedicte It supposed to be `std::plus<int>()`. I'm at fault, for not compiling the code before posting.

Comment: `error C2679: binary '+' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::vector<_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
`

Comment: @LoieBenedicte That's your fault now, the code is supposed [to work.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=11ebc196f13764c9801a5845bfaf7979-3725be9f9ce62f113fc473b4ae69c419).

Comment: I wasn't placing fault upon you.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<int> c;
const size_t minSize = std::min(a.size(), b.size());
c.reserve(minSize); // avoids useless reallocation
for (size_t i = 0; i < minSize; ++i)
    c.push_back(a[i] + b[i]);
```

Comment: @LoieBenedicte `min` is the minimum between two values.

Comment: It is native? I don't have to create it?

Comment: The `std::` prefix should give you a hint: it's part of the standard library. So yeah, it's "native".

Comment: Specifically, you'll have to `#include <algorithm>`

Comment: Oh, `min` is from `<algorithm>`.

Comment: @wlyles Right, I didn't think about mentioning the header name, I assumed OP would look it up if needed. Guess I shouldn't assume...